# What causes ssh client to claim password is a possible authentication but then not prompt the user for the password before rejecting the login?

Tags: security, authentication, sshd

What causes ssh client to claim password is a possible authentication but then not prompt the user for the password before rejecting the login?

For example:

```
ssh -v test@localhsot

> Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
> Next authentication method: publickey debug1: Trying private key:
> /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa debug1: Trying private key:
> /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa debug1: Trying private key:
> /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa debug1: Trying private key:
> /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519 debug1: No more authentication methods to
> try.
```

test@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the server has password authentication turned off

```
sudo grep -i password /etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

> PasswordAuthentication no
> ssh -v test@localhost
> ...

```
> debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password debug1:
> Next authentication method: publickey debug1: Trying private key:
> /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa debug1: Trying private key:
> /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa debug1: Trying private key:
> /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa debug1: Trying private key:
> /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519 debug1: No more authentication methods to

sudo vi /etc/ssh/ssh_config
sudo grep -i password /etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

> PasswordAuthentication yes
> `enter code here`...

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
test@localhost's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
```

Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux x86_64)